# Windows 8, Metro app: About dialog box guidelines or suggestions

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

Are About dialog boxes "dead" in Windows 8 Metro apps? I looked over quite a few apps and screenshots of apps in the Windows store, and did not find any "inspiration".

Is there any guidelines from Microsoft or any article that discusses this issue?

What do you think is the best way to show a dialog box/popup that shows the app name, version, author and a link to the app's home page?

I am thinking of a icon button in the bottom appbar, something like "About Appname", that opens a popup with this information. I am using C# and XAML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would place the About into the Settings pane via the Settings Charm using the Setting Contract. You can see the About in almost all of the apps in the Store today. Quick start on adding Settings can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh872190.aspx

Guidelines for app settings here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh770544.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know of any sample source code (xaml + C#) that shows how to implement an About popup via the Setting Charm? The Quick Start from your answer shows how to implement a (general) Settings popup.

Comment: A couple of decent articles here http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/03/06/creating-custom-settings-pane-xaml-windows-8.aspx and here http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2011/09/28/lighting-up-your-c-metro-apps-by-using-the-settings-contract.aspx

Comment: So much code for such a simple and common task reminds me of the Hello world program in C and Win32 API :) I think it should be made simpler, at least as simple as the Callisto SettingsFlyout control.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](http://socialeboladev.wordpress.com/2012/10/14/turn-any-usercontrol-into-a-pleasing-dialogflyout-in-windows-8/).

It lets you create dialogs/flyouts very easily from a UserControl. A few lines of boiler plate and you are done. Takes care of animation, UI management etc.